# Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65, trying to do CI/CD on AppCenter

Tags: ios, ionic-framework, capacitor, appcenter

I'm trying to do a CI/CD for my project on App Center, but im facing the following error:

*** ARCHIVE FAILED **

```
The following build commands failed:
    CpResource /Users/runner/work/1/s/app-dev/ios/App/App/public/Users/runner/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-cpioknpkpzmbvaamhsmwuyximnxr/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/App/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Applications/App.app/public (in target 'App' from project 'App')
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)*
```

Comment: I am facing a similar issue when I choose v13 for xCode: The following build commands failed:
 Run custom shell script 'Run Script'
(1 failure)
##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
##[section]Finishing: Xcode build (signed)
##[section]Starting: Xcode build (signed)